# Removal of download.checksum.sha-512 from artifact.xml file of Eclipse P2 repo generated through Tycho

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, tycho

I am using Maven Tycho for building Eclipse plug-ins(Tycho pomless version 3.0.3)

I would like to remove the `download.checksum.sha-512` from artifacts.xml present inside artifacts.jar of P2 repository
Can you please suggest how to stop generating SHA-512 in artifact.xml file

Example sha-512 entry in artifact.xml
 `<property name='download.checksum.sha-512' value='xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'>`

Comment: Why do you want to do that? See also https://github.com/eclipse-equinox/p2/pull/160

Comment: @howlger : The generated Eclipse P2 repose is not able to consume as eclipse target . When this repo is loaded in eclipse pde target getting error Sha512 error hence want to generate P2 repos without Sha512.

Comment: Sounds like you're about to shoot the messenger.